# Loop of regressions on input range - How can I avoid the for loop and improve performance?

Tags: r, performance, loops, regression, cross-validation

I am currently backtesting a strategy which involves an `lm()` regression and a probit `glm()` regression. I have a dataframe named `forBacktest` with 200 rows (1 for each day to backtest) and 9 columns : the first 8 (`x1` to `x8`) are the explanatory variables and the last one (`x9`) is the real value (which I am trying to explain in the regression). To do the regression, I have an other dataframe named `temp` which has like 1000 rows (one for each day) and a lot of columns, some of which are the `x1` to `x8` values and also the `x9` value.

But the tricky part is that I do not just generate a regression-model and then a loop for `predict` because **I select a part of the dataframe `temp` based on the values of `x1` which I split in 8 different ranges and then, according to the value `x1` of the dataframe `forBacktest`, I do a regression with a part of `temp` with `x1` in a given range.**

So what I do is that for each one of the 200 rows, I take `x1` and if `x1` is between 0 and 1 (for example) then I create a part of `temp` where all the `x1` are between 0 and 1, then I make a regression to explain `x9` with `x1`, `x2`, ... `x9` (just `x1+x2+...`, there is no `x1:x2`, `x1^2`,...) and then I use the `predict` function with the dataframe `forBacketst`. If I predict a positive value and if `x9` is positive then I increment a counter `success` by one (idem if both are negative), but if one is positive and the other negative, then `success` stays the same. Then I take the next row and so on. At the end of the 200 rows, I now have an average of the successes which I return. In fact, I have two averages : one for the `lm` regression and the other for the `glm` regression (same methodology, I just take `sign(x9)` for the variable to explain).

**So my question is: how can I efficiently do that in R, if possible without a big for loop with 200 iterations where for each iteration, it creates a part of the dataframe, makes the regressions, predict the two values, add them to a counter and so on?** (this is currently my solution but I find it too slow and not very R-like)

My code looks like that :

```
backtest<-function() {
    for (i in 1:dim(forBacktest)[1]) {
        x1 <- forBacktest[i,1]: x2 <- forBacktest[i,2] ... x9 <- forBacktest[i,9]
        a <- ifelse(x1>1.5,1.45,ifelse(x1>1,0.95,.... 
        b <- ifelse(x1>1.5,100,ifelse(x1>1,1.55,....
        temp2 <- temp[(temp$x1>=a/100)&(temp$x1<=b/100),]
        df <- dataframe(temp$x1,temp$x2,...temp$x9)
        reg <- lm(temp$x9~.,data=df)
        df2 <- data.frame(x1,x2,...x9)
        rReg <- predict(reg,df2)
        trueOrFalse <- ifelse(sign(rReg*x9)>0,1,0)
        success <- success+trueOrFalse
    }
    success
}
```

Comment: do you want to divide a column in a dataframe by specific range and then do lm() on to the values corresponding to one of those ranges?

Comment: yes that would be it

Comment: you understand that doing that would also remove the rows from all the other columns i.e. from x2 to x9, right?

Comment: yes I only want the regression when x1 is in a given range so only the x2...x9 values in the rows where x1 is in a given range. But I don't want to destroy the dataframe so i use temp2

Comment: the code has many changes.. i will post the edited code in a while

Comment: So your loop is to select ranges of input; is that essentially k-fold Cross-Validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is way much complicated. Things could be much much simpler..

Use the `cut()` and the `by()` function.

```
breaks <- 0:8 #this is the range by which you want to divide your data
divider <- cut(forBackTest$x1,breaks)
subsetDat <- by(forBackTest,INDICES = divider,data.frame) # this creates 8 dataframes
reg <- lapply(subsetDat,lm,formula=x9~.)
```

'reg' will now contain all the 8 lm objects corresponding to the 8 ranges. To predict for all these ranges use `lapply()` with `reg` and the `temp` dataframe. It will return you the predicted values for eight ranges

Few things to keep in mind:

- The method suggested above is simpler and easier to read. It will be
  faster than your for loops, but as the size of data frame increases,
  it could get slower.
- The by function takes a dataframe, and applies the function specified (`data.frame())` to the subsetted dataframe specified by INDICES and returns a list. So new dataframes are created and this could take up a lot of space if the size of dataframe is large.
- `*apply()` is much faster than for loops. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega?rq=1) to know more about them. The apply family comes handy for these kind of operations

Comment: but where would I write the x1,...x9 ? Like lm(x9~x1+x2) or lm,x9~x1+x2 because all of these return error

Comment: I got the error "cannot coerce class "lm" to a data.frame"

Comment: the code has many changes.. i will post the correct code in a while

Comment: I think you changed forBacktest and temp because the regression should be made on temp. But after the change of names it works well. On the other hand for the prediction I used `lapply(c(1:8),function(x){predict(reg[[x]],forBacktest})` and it returns 8 sets of 200 predictions (size of forBacktest) and it doesn't "split" forBacktest. How can I only return 200 predictions (and not 8*200) which would be the correct predictiosn for the value x1 of forBacktest ?

Comment: that's ok I just had to split forBacktest like I did for temp.